# AlpineJS on-click executed twice

Tags: javascript, laravel-blade, alpine.js

i'm new to AlpineJS and while learning it and implementing into my project, i found something bizarre that i can't resolve on my own. I have a Blade template that looks like this:

```
<form action="<some_url>" method="POST" style="display: contents">
@csrf
<button tabindex="-1" type="submit" class="focus:animate-ping w-full md:w-1/2 block hover:bg-gray-50 rounded-2xl">
    <img class="object-cover w-full h-full rounded-lg max-h-64 sm:max-h-96" src={{ <some_url> }}>
</button>

{{--img below is causing issues!--}}
<img x-data="{
        id: '{{ <some_hash_id> }}',
        _token: <csrf-token>
    }"
    @click="fetch('/bookmark', {method: 'POST',body: JSON.stringify(id)}).then(response => {
        if (response.ok)
            alert('Test - ok')
        else
            alert(`Test - problem`)
        })" 
    class="m-4 self-start" src="<some_img_url>">
    <input type="hidden" name="token2" value="{{ <another_token> }}">
</form>
```

The problem is that when i click on my **img** i get two alerts (both are the same, it's not a problem as on backend i haven't yet implemented an endpoint). I tried looking at AlpineJS docs, i tried using `.stop` and `.prevent`, i tried even without `form`. And result was always the same :(

All the time `npm run watch` is running and i'm always reloading the page with "empty cache" to make sure cache won't mess with it.

What might be a problem here? Thanks

Comment: So you get two alerts of the same message?  'Test - ok' & 'Test - problem' 
or you get two alerts one of each?

Comment: Two alerts of the same (both alerts are "Test - problem" as expected because i have no endpoint available right now)

Answer (score 1):

You can add `.debounce` to your `@click` trigger.
Take a look at the documentation [on.debounce - Alpine.js](https://alpinejs.dev/directives/on#debounce).

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping it in a function

```
<img x-data @click="() => { fetch('https://icanhazdadjoke.com/', {method: 'GET'}).then(response => {
        if (response.ok)
            alert('Test - ok')
        else
            alert(`Test - problem`)
        }) }" src="https://cdnjs.com/_/f7a2ebfb819c118086546e481876aef6.svg" />
```